# instantiate a Popup when click a button in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I want to show popup when press the button.

[image]

[image]

But now it looks like this

[image]

I have viewed many tutorials about how to make a popup when press the button.

But they all make the popup by script,not instantiate the prefab.

I'm not sure if I can instantiate the prefab as I hope or it's not a good idea.

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Purchase : MonoBehaviour,IPointerClickHandler
{
    public GameObject purchasePanel;
    public GameObject panelPosition;

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        GameObject instantiatedPurchase = Instantiate(purchasePanel, panelPosition.transform.position,panelPosition.transform.rotation) as GameObject;  
    instantiatedPurchase.transform.SetParent(panelPosition.transform);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably use Unity.UI, and just use a panel.

It is very easy (1) click "add canvas" (2) click "add panel".

Simply **turn it on and off** using

```
 .SetActive
```

from your code.  Enjoy!  As you can see it's this easy:

[image]

Try turning it on and off in the Editor with that toggle on `Inspector`.  In code it's just..

```
   public GameObject popupPanel;
   ...
   popupPanel.SetActive(false);  or...
   popupPanel.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: you mean not instantiate it every time, just keep one in the scene,and use SetActive to control it?

Comment: Yes, that is what he means.

Comment: Make sure your pivot is also set in the prefab

Comment: hi @ChenxingZheng -- correct, do that.  generally never Instantiate or use prefabs for UI, these days.  It is incredibly simple with Unity UI.

Comment: hi @ChenxingZheng i expanded the answer for you

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you! I got it!

Comment: great!!!  don't forget you can have more than one panel .. more than one popup .. just turn them on and off

Answer (score 0):

I describe my way how to make popup.
There is a .gif how it looks like.
[image]

And there is [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1327989/open-a-popup-window-with-text-and-images-when-clic.html) where it is described (Dacke is nickname there).