# Pausing an animation whilst Unity UI is active

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a two modals that I'm designing to go over my project in Unity, one for a quick tutorial and one for more information about the project, I also have an animation playing in the background.

I'd like the animation to pause whenever the modals are active and over the top of the animation, if you can't see the animation, why have it playing? Exactly.

My code so far doesn't work and I'm unsure why.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ModalPauseController : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject tutorialModal;
public ScrubberAnimationController nac;

public void TutorialModalIsOpen()
{
    if (tutorialModal.activeInHierarchy == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("The tutorial panel is active!!");
        nac.UserClickedPauseButton();
    }
}
}
```

`nac.UserClickedPauseButton` refers to another script where it pauses the animation.

So far whenever I toggle the active state of the modals, whether it be via the inspector, or in game, I no feedback in my debug.

Comment: hold it dude!  how are you making these "modals"?  **You should absolutely definitely be using Unity.UI dude** ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35643548/294884 ps explain

Comment: I was just making them active or not depending on what was clicked, it's a new canvas with everything in it, it's just being activated within the scene when a "more info" button is pressed.

Comment: regarding the script which turns on and off the Canvas.  and the script above `ModalPauseController`.  is either of those scripts actually ON the Canvas in question?  if so, move them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite tricky writing code like that, because if you think about it

## *the code itself will be not active !!!*

As a rule say you have a panel "X" which is a popup or something like that - something which comes and goes.

The rule is you must have the "controller" for that thing

## *on some **other** item*, not on itself!

Here's an example:

[image]

The "megabomb" is a popup sign which goes on and off.  There it is on

[image]

and there it is off. There's a script which controls the megabomb on-offness.

[image]

Notice there is a "wrapper" for the megabomb item. In UI the "wrapper" is very simply an empty panel. It is invisible. Note that the wrapper ***always stays on***.

The script goes on the wrapper - that's it.

Note that very commonly the "megabomb" item itself has a "wrapper" - a gray transparent background.  So, when the popup appears, the game behind goes all gray and you have the popup over that.  Don't forget in that case the gray background would be labelled "megabomb" in this example and the actual popup green (or whatever) panel would be below that. (Indeed the popup panel itself will very likely have many parts -- images, buttons, borders, etc etc.) Do not try to use the "gray background" as the "wrapper which holds the script. You need a completely separate wrapper "outside of everything" which does nothing other than hold the script.

{BTW this is yet another thing which screws up experienced-developer-who-are-new-to-Unity. Normally you'd have "some other class" run the popup, but there is "no other class" in Unity - everything is a singleton if you will, since it is an ECS system, not normal OO. You have to literally have ***another game object*** (the one labelled 'wrapper' in the example) which controls the game object in question (the one labelled 'megabombs' in the example). AND it has to be always active.}

Note - if you prefer the "controller script" can actually be anywhere else (it does not have to be on an game object "holding" the item in question). However certainly at first I encourage you to use the system of putting it as a "wrapper" as shown, it has many advantages. (Not to mention ultimately it might be a Prefab, etc etc.) Definitely do that when starting out.

It's just "one of those things they don't mention" about Unity: very often many many things in your scene will need a "wrapper" object. (The same is true for other reasons such as positioning, relative rotations, etc, too.)

BTW as I mention in a comment. If you are making a popup, it *must* be done with Unity.UI (ie, click "add canvas" - always remember to set to 'scale with screen size' , then click "add panel", then click "add text").

Comment: I've done all of this, it's within it's own wrapper now and the script that checks if it's active or not is on the wrapper, but still, the check if active script returns me nothing.

Comment: Ok, so I sort out got it to work, I added the `modalIsActive` script to the nac script, the debug notices if it's open or not, which is good when changed to `public void Update()`. But now when the modal is open it quick changes between paused and unpaused on every update I think it is. I think this has something to do with the update loop, I really don't know though.